# Code can be recovered for iOS app with debugging turned on

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging

If I distribute an iOS app with debugging turned on how much of the code can be reconstructed by an evil person?

I am asking about an evil person being able to quickly reconstruct the source code, not about philosophical questions.

The core of my question is: what aspects of the source code are inserted by the compiler (gcc or llvm in my particular case) into the source code.